# Send request to other service after specifying axios.default.baseURL

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm new to Axios and React, I'm creating React app that performs CRUD operations using Axios to fetch data from API.

In the `api/agent.ts` I specified Axios config for my API I developed.

`api/agent.ts`

```
import axios, { AxiosError, AxiosResponse } from "axios"

// my API url
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8800/api"

// api response
const responseBody = <T>(response: AxiosResponse<T>) => response.data

const requests = {
    get: <T>(url: string) => axios.get<T>(url).then(responseBody),
    post: <T>(url: string, body: {}) =>
        axios.post<T>(url, body).then(responseBody),
    put: <T>(url: string, body: {}) =>
        axios.put<T>(url, body).then(responseBody),
    del: <T>(url: string) => axios.delete<T>(url).then(responseBody),
}

// other API requests...
```

Now in certain components, I want to use Axios to make a request from the other services not from the `axios.defaults.baseURL` which I configured in `api/agent.ts`, for example, I want to make a request from my `dummyData.json` in the `public` folder

`public/dummyData/dummy_data.json`

```
{
    "message": "data fetched successfully",
    "data": [{
            "id": "manga-jo986949",
            "thumbnail_url": "https://avt.mkklcdnv6temp.com/27/p/22-1602825472.jpg",
            "title": "Memorize",
            "latest_chapter_title": "Chapter 69",
            "latest_chapter": 69,
            "latest_chapter_url": "https://readmanganato.com/manga-jo986949/chapter-69",
            "views_count": 39037474,
            "authors": ["Jeongha", "Ro Yujin"],
            "last_updated": "Oct-31-2021 14:32",
            "url": "https://readmanganato.com/manga-jo986949"
        },
        {
            "id": "manga-uj971844",
            "thumbnail_url": "https://avt.mkklcdnv6temp.com/3/c/14-1583489799.jpg",
            "title": "Vampire Knight Memories",
            "latest_chapter_title": "Chapter 33",
            "latest_chapter": 33,
            "latest_chapter_url": "https://readmanganato.com/manga-uj971844/chapter-33",
            "views_count": 1853526,
            "authors": ["ji", "tom"],
            "last_updated": "Jul-10-2021 03:33",
            "url": "https://readmanganato.com/manga-uj971844"
        }
    ]
}
```

This are the components that I used to fetch and display `dummy_data.json`

`fetcher.tsx`

```
import axios from "axios"

export async function get<T>(path: string): Promise<T> {
    const { data } = await axios.get(path)
    return data
}
```

`mangaList.tsx`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { get } from "../fetcher"

export default function MangaList() {
    const [data, setData] = useState<Manga[]>([])

    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await get<Manga[]>("/dummy_data.json")
            setData(result)
        } catch (err) {
            throw err
        }
        console.log("manga data: ", data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Welcome to Manga Online</h2>
            // some code ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

When I redirect to `/MangaList`, the console says that `GET http://localhost:8800/api/dummy_data.json 404 (Not Found)`. The Axios is still using `axios.defaults.baseURL` to fetch the irrelevant data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `axios defaultUrl`. But in your case it's better to use the axios instance rather than updating the `axios default` parameters.

This is how we can create a axios instance.

```js
// axios instance 1
import axios from 'axios'

const axiosInstanceRemote = axios.create({
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:8800/api"
)}
```

and your request is look like:

```js
const requests = {
    get: <T>(url: string) => axiosInstanceRemote .get<T>(url).then(responseBody),
    post: <T>(url: string, body: {}) =>
        axiosInstanceRemote .post<T>(url, body).then(responseBody),
   ...similar
}
```

In here, you're using the specific instance rather than axios defaults.

And for your local api call:

```js
// fetch.jsx
import axios from "axios"

export async function get<T>(path: string): Promise<T> {
    const { data } = await axios.get(path)
    return data
}
```

you can either create another instance (similar as instance 1 with different base url) or use the default axios request.

Here is the [official doc](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance).

Answer (score 1):

From [axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) you have *baseURL* and *url*

`baseURL` will be prepended to `url` when making requests. So you can define `baseURL` as `http://127.0.0.1:8800` and make your requests to `/url`

> ```
>  // `url` is the server URL that will be used for the request
>  url: '/user',
>
>  // `baseURL` will be prepended to `url` unless `url` is absolute.
>  // It can be convenient to set `baseURL` for an instance of axios to pass relative URLs
>  // to methods of that instance.
>  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
> ```